# Nested Generics with Wildcards

Tags: java, generics

Why does this work:

```
List<?> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

while this gives a type dismatch error:

```
List<List<?>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

Why is this?
Ist there a way around this, without using raw types?

Comment: Why? Because `list.add(new ArrayList<String>())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
List<? extends List<?>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

Note: you should be aware that when you use a collection like List you will only be able to use it in "read only" mode (except for adding null values).

Answer (score 3):

To actually answer your question:

In the first case, "list" holds a list of one particular, unspecified type - in this case, Integer.

In the second case, "list" holds a list of lists, but each of the sublists may be of any particular type, but the following would be perfectly fine (note the types of the two lists being added):

```
List<List<?>> list = new LinkedList<List<?>>();
list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
list.add(new LinkedList<Double>());
```

It's very similar to the reason why you can't do

```
List<Object> listO = new List<Number>();
```

There are operations that would be perfectly valid on your list of lists of ? that would be illegal on the list of lists of Integers.

In order to do what you want (have a list of lists, where all the sublists are unique to a particular type), I think Zed's answer is about as close as you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The way around this is

```
List<List<?>> list = new LinkedList<List<?>>();
```

You've not really lost anything there, either - your specification of Integer wasn't going to be helpful anywhere, since `list` defined the inner Lists as using `?`

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
List<?> list1 = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and post, but I don't seem how the answers fixed c0d3x's problem.

If you do

```
List<List<?>> list = new LinkedList<List<?>>();
```

How is he gonna call this method for each inner Integer list in the outer list?

```
public void doSomeThingWithAIntegerList(List<Integer> list){
    for(Integer i : list){
        // use it for some purpose
    }
}
```