# Why can't a Generic type containing a Generic type be assigned to a Generic typed class of wildcard type

Tags: java, generics

Sorry if the title seems confusing, but some examples are in order.

Let's say I have some Java class with a generic type parameter:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
}
```

I can create a variable typed to store an object, with the generic parameter set to, say a `String`. Java will also let me assign that variable to another variable but with the generic parameter set to the wildcard `<?>` type:

```
GenericClass<String> stringy = ...
GenericClass<?> generic = stringy; // OK
```

However, when working with a class with a generic parameter, if you set the type of that parameter to be generic, you can't then assign an object of that class to an identically typed/genericized type where the latter (inner/nested) parameter is of the wildcard type `<?>`:

```
GenericClass<GenericClass<String>> stringy = ...
GenericClass<GenericClass<?>> generic = stringy; // Compile Error

// And just in case that is confusing, a more
// realistic example involving Collections:
List<GenericClass<String>> stringy = ...
List<GenericClass<?>> generic = stringy; // Compile Error
```

The specific compile error is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<GenericClass<String>> to List<GenericClass<?>>
```

Intuitively I would think that the assignment in question should not be a problem. So why is this assignment an problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341093/nested-generics-with-wildcards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem your facing is denominated [Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

```
List<GenericClass<String>> stringy = ...
List<GenericClass<?>> generic = stringy;
generic.add(new GenericClass<Integer>());
```

If this wasn't a compile error, then the last line of code would be possible.

You could get around the error by doing this:

```
 List<? extends GenericClass<?>> generic = stringy;
```

but you can not use `add` also because you don't really know what `? extends GenericClass<?>` is (Covariance once again). In this case you can only enumerate through the List and expect `GenericClass<?>`.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, that's because `List<GenericClass<String>>` is not a subtype of `List<GenericClass<?>>`. In order to make it work, you could do something like

```
List<? extends GenericClass<?>> generic = stringy
```

which should work as expected (though is pretty ugly...).

See, for example, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341093/nested-generics-with-wildcards) for more details