# Why it is not possible to assign a List<List<String>> to a variable of the type List<List<?>>?

Tags: java, generics

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<List<?>> list2 = list; // compiletime error
```

I was surprised to discover that this is not possible. I expected that this is possible.

I didnt find an answer to this question on goole.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476447/why-cant-a-generic-type-containing-a-generic-type-be-assigned-to-a-generic-type?rq=1

Comment: If no one is taking action, I'll post the accepted answer from that question.

Comment: yes. it explains it. thank you very much.

Comment: @tbodt If you are nervous waiting for the question to be closed as duplicate, then post the link to the duplicate question in the comment. I must warn you that the community often gets *very* angry at plagiarized posts.