# Mixing nested type parameters and wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics

Why does trying to compile

```
public class GenericsFail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        accept(new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
    }

    public static void accept(Map<String, List<?>> multiMap) {}
}
```

give the error

```
GenericsFail.java:7: error: method accept in class GenericsFail cannot be applied to given types;
                accept(new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
                ^
  required: Map<String,List<?>>
  found: HashMap<String,List<String>>
  reason: actual argument HashMap<String,List<String>> cannot be converted to Map<String,List<?>> by method invocation conversion
```

The wildcard is only allowed if it's not nested inside `List`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested Generics with Wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341093/nested-generics-with-wildcards)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that the `?` in `List<?>` could be "anything", but a *different* "anything" in each `Map` entry. That is, it would accept a `List<String>` in one entry, and a `List<Integer>` in another.

But you are passing in a `Map` that has the *same* type of `List` in every entry, so the type is not bound in the same way or the to same degree for freedom.

The "fix" is to lock the type to a specific type, but still being "anything" - just the *same* "anything* in every entry, by typing the method:

```
public static <T> void accept(Map<String, List<T>> multiMap) // complies
```

or if your method really doesn't need to know *which* type, use a wildcard to wrap the type:

```
public static void accept(Map<String, ? extends List<?>> multiMap) // compiles
```

This last version works because the type of the list, although being a wildcard, is fixed to an unknown, but *consistent*, type when called.

I find the typed version easier to read (and code), and the type is there for use should you decide later that your method needs to know the type.

Comment: Aha, it's obvious now you say it.  Perhaps I missed the solution because, in my actual code, I'm not interested in what the List contains since I only need to call toString() on the elements.

Comment: Note that the two signatures above have other differences. `<T> void accept(Map<String, List<T>> multiMap)` will not accept `Map<String, List<?>>`; i.e., `List<T>` requires a specific, defined type for the List<>. It also will not accept subtypes of List<> (e.g., Arraylist<T>) unless they are "cast" as List<T>. But, `void accept(Map<String, ? extends List<?>> multiMap)` **will** accept `Map<String, List<?>>`; i.e., it will accept _any_ type (or subtype) of list.

Answer (score 4):

To be more general

```
void accept(Map<String, ? extends List<?>> multiMap)
```

Comment: I think that better expresses my intention.  Can you help me understand why I need the bounded wildcard in there?

Comment: in a simpler example, say you want to accept a set of numbers. `accept(Set<Number>)` is too narrow, it won't accept a `Set<Integer>`. you need `accept(Set<? extends Number>)`, then it can accept `Set<Number>, Set<Integer>, Set<Long>` etc.

Comment: If I had written `accept(new HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>>())` I could understand why the bounded wildcard would be necessary, since `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`.  But in this question, I'm still not clear.  Perhaps I'll never fully understand generics... ;-)

Comment: I've just found http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104 which addresses this question, too

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example of why the compilator cannot accept this parameter :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //if this would be accepted here ...
        accept(new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
    }

    public static void accept(Map<String, List<?>> multiMap) {
        //this is valid considering the type of multiMap parameter,
        //but would not work with the actual passed parameter.
        multiMap.put("test", new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
```