# Assigning a variable from nested generics in generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

If I have the following code:

```
public class DummyClass<T> {
    public List<T> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    public Set<List<T>> getListSet() {
        return new HashSet<List<T>>();
    }
}
```

and I have a `DummyClass<?> dummy`,

I can do

```
List<?> list = dummy.getList();
```

without any errors.

However,

```
Set<List<?>> listSet = dummy.getListSet();
```

gives the compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<List<capture#1-of ?>> to Set<List<?>>
```

for the line assigning `dummy.getListSet()`.

Why can't I assign `dummy.getListSet()` to a `Set<List<?>>`?

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056421/mixing-nested-type-parameters-and-wildcards-in-java

Answer (score 1):

However you can do following:

`Set<? extends List<?>> listSet = listSet = dummyClass.getListSet();`

See the excellent article [Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

First is important to know, that the compiler replace *?* operator with *Object* class. So when you write this:

```
DummyClass<?> dummy
```

your class definition will look like this:

```
public class DummyClass<Object>
```

and methods like this:

```
public List<Object> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<Object>();
}
public Set<List<Object>> getListSet() {
    return new HashSet<List<Object>>();
}
```

You can write

```
List<?> list = new List<Object>();
```

but not

```
Set<List<?>> set = new HashSet<List<Object>>();
```