# Incompatible generic type for result returned by Java iterator

Tags: java, generics, iterator, incompatibility

I have an object which is a type of Map, and I am trying to iterate it with iterator. However, I cannot pass the compile, the code are as following.

```
// Returned from other method, and the run time type is Map<String, B>
Map<String, ? extends A> map = ...

// Option 1: cannot pass.
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

// Option 2: cannot pass either.
// Where B is a subclass extends from A
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, B>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Iterator explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the foreach loop instead of using the Iterator directly

```
Map<String, ? extends A> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends A> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    A value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you. But can you explain why my code didn't work?

Comment: @ChazyT When you have `?` unknown, it doesn't mean that another `?` will be equal to it. I am not sure why this works with for-each.  In general, I avoid using `? extends` as it usually causes confusion. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store the `Iterator` in a variable, instead of this

```
// ERROR
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

you have to do this:

```
Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

The reason for the extra `? extends` is the wildcard nested in in the `Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>` declaration. If you had a variable of type

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>>
```

then in principle each entry could have a value of a different subtype of A, so each `Map.Entry` would be of a different type. By contrast,

```
Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>>
```

means that each entry is of a single type. (But you don't know what type it is, since it's a wildcard.)

In practice, this doesn't matter for `Iterator` since you're only getting objects of type `Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>` out of it. But if you had some other type that allowed you to put things into it (such as a `Set`) then the difference would be significant. For example,

```
Set<? extends Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>>
```

would only allow getting entries from the set, but

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, ? extends A>>
```

would allow adding entries to the set, and those entries might contain different subtypes of A, possibly polluting the set.

For further discussion on this, see

- [Angelika Langer - Generics FAQ - What do multilevel wildcards mean?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20do%20multilevel%20wildcards%20mean?)

as well as these Stack Overflow questions:

- [Java generics, nested collection of wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293871/java-generics-nested-collection-of-wildcard)
- [Nested Generics with Wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341093/nested-generics-with-wildcards)
- [Mixing nested type parameters and wildcards in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056421/mixing-nested-type-parameters-and-wildcards-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I this this should do the trick

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends A> entry : map.entrySet())
{
   String key = entry.getKey();
    A value = entry.getValue();
}
```